# How can I refute the deletion of an answer of mine for being a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, deleted-answers

Recently I found two almost identical questions on Stack Overflow that both were over 8 months old and had no accepted nor upvoted answers. I provided an identical answer to both of them. That might have been wrong, I understand that. Here's my issue.

A moderator deleted one of my answers on a said question and had this to say:

> Please don't post identical answers to multiple questions. Post one good answer, then vote/flag to close the other questions as duplicates. If the question is not a duplicate, tailor your answers to the question.

Let me break this comment down:

- **Post one good answer, then vote/flag to close the other questions as duplicates**

For one, I cannot vote on the other question because I cannot vote on my own posts. Second, I cannot flag the question because it has no upvoted nor accepted answer.

- **If the question is not a duplicate, tailor your answers to the question.**

The question *was* a duplicate, hence I didn't see the need to change my answer. I couldn't mark it as a duplicate, I couldn't vote or flag either one, but they were duplicates so I answered both of them.

Now that one of my answers was removed from this moderator, there is no way for me to refute his point and try and undelete it.

I feel powerless in this situation. I had a reason for a duplicate answer, and maybe my reasoning is flawed. However, in the case that my reasoning is *not* flawed, how am I supposed to convey my reasoning with no opportunity to do so since commenting on deleted answers is not allowed?

Comment: You need to wait a little bit.  If your answer is up voted then you can flag/vote to close as a dupe.  It would be nice to do it all at once but SO wants to make sure there is a "good" answer on the Q before you can use it as a dupe target.

Comment: On top of this, the moderator deleted my answer on the older question, I'd rather he deleted my answer on the newer question so I could eventually mark _that_ as the duplicate but hence I cannot convey this message to the moderator.

Comment: You can always flag one of your post for moderator attention and explain to them what is going on.

Comment: Thanks @NathanOliver. I'll try that.

Comment: As a programmer you should know the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), so the same applies to writing answers.

Comment: I appreciate the lecture, I'm aware of DRY. This wasn't meant to excuse my duplicate answer but rather to get to the root of the problem which is mediating a deleted answer.

Comment: Except your making excuses.  You could have easily flagged one of the questions for moderator attention, explain you thought it was a duplicate of the single question you answered but you didn't do that.  There are many times a user will accidentally create two accounts, ask the same question twice, that's how you deal with a question you describe.  If the same user posts the same question twice, it's easier, because the system recognizes the question was submitted by the same user or I simply have enough reputation to do that whatever applies.  Next time flag and move one question

Comment: (The proper thing was done) eventually.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm not making excuses about anything. Also, speaking of duplicates, your comment above suggests to do the same thing that NathanOliver suggested to do before you which was already a sufficient answer for me. No need for verbosity or any future comments, this question has been answered.

Answer (score 8):

**TL;DR:**

1.) Custom flag one of the questions, and explain the situation. A moderator will review the situation, and - if he agrees with you - undelete your answer (unlikely).

2.) If you'll ever come into a situation like this again, only answer one of the questions, and be patient or ask for help in a chatroom.

---

To answer your question directly: You can start of simply by raising a custom moderator flag ("In need of moderator intervention") on the question, and explain your situation and reasoning using the available text-field. The moderator handling your flag will then review the situation, and act according to his assessment of the situation.

---

Now, regarding your specific situation: What you did was simply not the best approach. Stackoverflow is meant to be a collection of questions & answers, where one question has one answer, and not more. That's why we have the duplicate-system in place.

What you could have done instead of posting the same exact answer to two separate questions would've been this:

- Post the answer to the question that's in your opinion better suited for being the duplicate target
- (Edit the question, if necessary)
- Wait for that answer to be upvoted
- Dupe-flag the other question

We all know that new questions / answers, especially in low-traffic tags, may take a while to be upvoted, but that's simply the way it goes. If you want this situation to be handled as fast as possible, it's also a possibility to hop into a chat-room, and ask people if they're willing to help you out with your problem.

*Note: Don't hop into the chatroom, link the question with a message saying "Upvote pliz", and instantly leave again (we had that happen a few times already).*

Best course of action would be to explain the situation, and then link to both questions. The users in the chatroom then can review your answer, the questions at hand, and can then decide to vote on it. It's also quite possible that one of the users has a gold-badge for one of the tags that the question is tagged with, which'd result in an instantly closed question, if the user agrees with your request.